# How do you create and detect one-time Server Sent Events?

Tags: php, javascript, post, server-sent-events

I'm trying to have client-side instances be able to detect when other client-side instances post something, then retrieve that post. (So I guess it's like a chat system, but for my implementation it's not meant for that)

I'm trying to use Server Side Events.

I noticed that with a basic SSE structure, where the client's Javascript listens to incoming server PHP outputs, I get a continuous stream of messages every few seconds or so.

**How can I have a user instance POST data (through an HTML form) to the server PHP script, which receives the data and turns it into SSE-Style JSON, outputs (echo) it, then have all user-instances detect and retrieve that one post, and only once?**

For example, this my the basic SSE structure:

**PHP script to receive POST data and output JSON data (stream.php)**

```
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    function sendMsg($name, $msg) {
      echo "data: {\n";
      echo "data: \"name\": \"$name\", \n";
      echo "data: \"msg\": \"$msg\", \n";
      echo "data: \"id\": 1\n";
      echo "data: }\n";
      echo PHP_EOL;
      ob_flush();
      flush();
    }

    sendMsg($_POST['name'], $_POST['message']);
```

**Client Side Javascript to listen for and receive Server Sent Data (inside index.php)**

```
var source = new EventSource('stream.php');
        }               

        source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            $("#stream").prepend(
                "<div class='newitem'>" +
                data.name + ": " + data.msg + 
                "</div>"
            )
        }, false);
```

And under the `<div id="stream">` , I will get a continuous stream of `undefined`, one every 3 seconds, as I should. Like this:

```
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
....
```

Now, how can I have a form like the following, and have the above stream detect and display the submitted data?

**HTML Form sending data to server (inside index.php)**

```
<form action="stream.php" method="POST">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text"/>

    <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Send"/>    
</form>
```

So hopefully, my stream under `<div id="stream">` will look something like this?

```
undefined undefined
Bob: Hello
undefined undefined
....
```

Currently, **even though stream.php is in fact retrieving the form data, for some reason it will not show.** It will still keep reading undefined (or, rather, not displaying anything).

If I can achieve this, I plan to just filter out `undefined undefined` messages, so that only defined messages will be displayed in the client-side stream.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use [Web Sockets](http://www.websocket.org/). [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) is great if you're using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) but there are also [php libraries](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) to help you out,